# How do I access an eav attribute field defined and marked up in the billing step of Magento checkout?

Tags: magento, events, checkout, entity-attribute-value

I need to access it in an observer just before collectTotals() is run. I'm using the sales_quote_collect_totals_before observer and it seems to be doing everything else I need it to do. I want to be able to access this attribute when the event is triggered

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `sales_quote_address_collect_totals_before` event in your module. like this:

```
<events>
    <sales_quote_address_collect_totals_before>
        <observers>
            <namespace_your_modulename_custom_event>
                <class>your_observer_class</class>
                <method>yourObserverMethod</method>
            </namespace_your_modulename_custom_event>
        </observers>
    </sales_quote_address_collect_totals_before>
</events>
```

In your observer model the method should look like this:

```
public function yourObserverMethod(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{

    // code goes to here 
}
```

Comment: I'm aware of the getQuoteAddress method. How can I access the eav attribute that I've used in the billing address form through the getQuoteAddress object?

Comment: edited! sorry @Ashwin I used getQuoteAddress as example code. For billing details you may use `$observer->getQuoteItem()->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()`